# Is this $(document).ready being fired twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

This is the official shorthand for doc ready (in jQuery):

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    // do something
});
```

In some cases, we add document on handlers. For example:

```
$(function () {
    $(document)
        .on('click', '.save-order-button', function (e) {
            saveOrder(e);
        })
        .on('change', '.select-product-quantity', handleChangeProductQuantity)
})
```

But my question is this: given the `$(document).on` example above, how would you add logic to be called on doc ready?

I would do it this way:

```
$(function () {
    $(document)
        .on('click', '.save-order-button', function (e) {
            saveOrder(e);
        })
        .on('change', '.select-product-quantity', handleChangeProductQuantity);

   
    // do below on $(document).ready
    if ($('#isNewCustomer').val() === 'true') {
        $('.profile').hide();
        $('.links').hide();
    }

    callSomeOtherFunction();
})
```

A coworker prefers this way:

```
$(function () {
    $(document)
        .on('click', '.save-order-button', function (e) {
            saveOrder(e);
        })
        .on('change', '.select-product-quantity', handleChangeProductQuantity)
        .ready(() => {
            if ($('#isNewCustomer').val() === 'true') {
                $('.profile').hide();
                $('.links').hide();
            }
            callSomeOtherFunction();
        });
})
```

Is either way ok?
Is my coworker's way fine?
Is doc ready being fired twice in my coworker's example?
If we did both, for example, some in `.ready(() =>`, my coworker's way, and also some my way, would doc ready be getting fired twice? Which would be fired first?

Thx in advance.

Comment: What does _"This is the official shorthand for doc ready"_? How can this be official if it's not even pure vanilla JS? Why would you even use jQuery in 2023?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: There is no reason to use jQuery for more than 5 years. https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Your question about using jQuery is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: You've asked if your two options are good and you linked to a dying library. My answer is, you don't need jQuery and using it increases the size and download time of your app for no reason. That makes both options bad in my opinion. _"Is either way ok?"_ No, I wouldn't accept it in a code review.

Comment: Ok, thank  you.  I'll wait for some experienced jQuery users to come along and offer some useful comments.

Comment: That nested ready handler is just weird. Don't do that. You actually can just drop the outer wrapper, attaching delegated event handlers to `document` itself works without waiting.

Answer (score 2):

> Is either way ok? Is my coworkers way fine?

Both work as intended. But the jQuery authors write the following about using [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> Query offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - `$( handler )`
> - `$( document ).ready( handler )`
> - `$( "document" ).ready( handler )`
> - `$( "img" ).ready( handler )`
> - `$().ready( handler )`
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work **but are deprecated**. This is because the selection has no bearing on the behavior of the `.ready()` method, which is inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's behavior. For example, the third syntax works with "document" which selects nothing. The fourth syntax waits for the document to be ready but implies (incorrectly) that it waits for images to become ready.

So this favours your version of the code.

> Is doc `ready` being fired twice in my coworkers example?

Yes, all callbacks on the ready event get called, also handlers that are attached **after** the DOM is ready, which is the case in the alternative code.

The jQuery documentation ensures this:

> If the DOM becomes ready and the browser fires `DOMContentLoaded` before the code calls `.ready( handler )`, the function handler will still be executed.

I would certainly go for your version of the code. The additional `.ready()` call gives the impression that the author has doubts whether that code can be executed *synchronously*, but of course it can, because it is already ensured that the DOM is ready.

Another way to look at it, is that the alternative code doesn't need the `$(function () {    })` wrapper around it, and then it makes more sense to have the `.ready()` handler.

But the main objection remains: `.ready()` is deprecated since jQuery 3.0

Comment: This is a most excellent response.  Thank you!